# How to integrate Xbox Live Services in UWP games?

Tags: uwp, xbox

Firstly. I'm a complete noob having little knowledge. I am exploring around limitations of UWP. Out of curiosity I just want to know whether Xbox Live Service such as Achievements support can be integrated into UWP games or not?

So my question is, Does UWP game(which works on pc,mobile,xbox,hololens)  support Xbox Achievements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does UWP game(which works on pc,mobile,xbox,hololens) support Xbox Achievements??

The short answer should be yes. According to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-live/developer-program-overview)

> Achievements, Multiplayer and the full of Social features is NOT supported for titles in the Xbox Live Creators Program.

So that the Xbox Live enabled title you used should be ID@Xbox. For how to integrate it with UWP games as an ID developer please reference [Get started using Visual Studio for UWP games](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-live/get-started-with-partner/get-started-with-visual-studio-and-uwp).